# How to ignore quotes while splitting strings python

Tags: python

I want to split the below mentioned string:

```
  lin=' <abc<hd <> "abc\"d\" ef" '
```

into

```
 [<abc<hd <>,  "abc\"d\" ef"]
```

However my problem is when I split the string using `re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', lin, 0)`. I get

```
['abc', 'ef']
```

Can someone please guide me as to how can I split the string in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using *regular expression*.

```
import re
line = ' <abc<hd <> "abc\"d\" ef" ' 

match = list(re.findall(r'(<[^>]+>)\s+("(?:\"|[^"])+")', line)[0])

print(match)
#['<abc<hd <>', '"abc"d" ef"']
```

Another way to do it.

```
print(re.split(r'\s+(?=")', line.strip())) #split on white space only if followed by a quote.
#['<abc<hd <>', '"abc"d" ef"']
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you have some extra whitespace on the beginning and end of your string, so doing `lin .strip()` will remove that.

You can then use `str.split()` to split at the first `"`:

```
>>> lin.strip().split(' "', 1)
['<abc<hd <>', 'abc"d" ef"']
```

The `1` we use as a second argument tells python to only split it once, and so not split at every other `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another RegEx solution

```
import re
lin=' <abc<hd <> "abc\"d\" ef" '
matching = re.match("\s+(.*?)\s+(\"(.*)\")", lin)
print [matching.group(1), matching.group(2)]
```

**Output**

```
['<abc<hd <>', '"abc"d" ef"']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lin=' <abc<hd <> "abc\"d\" ef" '
>>> lin.split('"', 1)
[' <abc<hd <> ', 'abc"d" ef" ']
```

Comment: what does parameter 1 within split indicate

Comment: This isn't what OP wants. Check the extra whitespace your answer provides

Comment: strip() is straight forward. No need to present everything spoon-ready.

Comment: @user2799617: Be nice.